# Install ginac on Ubuntu 16.04 - no such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, installation, file-search, ginac

I am trying to install ginac on Ubuntu 16.04
I have installed ginac-tools from sources.
However, when I copy the example given on the website into my code, it says: cannot find such file or directory (in the #include ginac line).

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ginac/ginac.h>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace GiNaC;

    int main()
    {
         symbol x("x"), y("y");
         ex poly;

         for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
             poly += factorial(i+16)*pow(x,i)*pow(y,2-i);

         cout << poly << endl;
         return 0;
    }
```

I also tried searching for ginac.h, but could not find it on my system. 
How can I fix this?

EDIT: I had to install libginac-dev too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to install libginac-dev too.